# How do I Program the Create 2?

Tags: irobot-create, programming-languages

I just un-boxed and set the `Create 2` to charge overnight.

How do I program it? Where is the software?

Comment: Do you mean this thing?  http://www.irobot.com/About-iRobot/STEM/Create-2.aspx.  There are some projects to try here: http://www.irobot.com/About-iRobot/STEM/Create-2/Projects.aspx

Comment: @Andy, that is a great answer, don't be shy about posting an actual answer.  Comments are helping to improve posts.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Computer, Arduino, Raspberry Pi or other device that can communicate via serial (using a [Create 2 USB cable](http://store.irobot.com/communication-cable-create-2/product.jsp?productId=54235746&cp=3335976&parentPage=family) or [build your own](http://www.irobot.com/~/media/MainSite/PDFs/About/STEM/Create/Create_2_Serial_to_USB_Cable_Creation.pdf?la=en)) or Bluetooth (if you have a something like the Rootooth or [build your own](http://www.irobot.com/~/media/MainSite/PDFs/About/STEM/Create/Bluetooth_Serial.pdf?la=en)) and program that device to connect and interact with the Create 2.
[Please checkout the Create 2 Site at iRobot](http://www.irobot.com/About-iRobot/STEM/Create-2.aspx)

On the Create 2 site you will also find the [Getting Started](http://www.irobot.com/About-iRobot/STEM/Create-2/Projects.aspx) page that will link you to the Create 2 Open Interface Specification and several example projects.

As Andy mentioned a direct link to the Open Interface Specification is [here](http://www.irobot.com/~/media/MainSite/PDFs/About/STEM/Create/iRobot_Roomba_600_Open_Interface_Spec.pdf) as well.

Answer (score 0):

Looking through the links posted by Andy, here are some simple commands I extracted from iRobot's python script:

```
if k == 'P':   # Passive
    self.sendCommandASCII('128')

elif k == 'S': # Safe
    self.sendCommandASCII('131')

elif k == 'F': # Full
    self.sendCommandASCII('132')

elif k == 'C': # Clean
    self.sendCommandASCII('135')

elif k == 'D': # Dock
    self.sendCommandASCII('143')

elif k == 'SPACE': # Beep
    self.sendCommandASCII('140 3 1 64 16 141 3')

elif k == 'R': # Reset
    self.sendCommandASCII('7')
```

They will more then likely have a full command set either provided with the system, or available online - but here are some basic commands.

The connection to the system is made via serial, and it would appear from this script as if ASCII commands are all it takes to get it up and running.

Plug, open a serial terminal, and play.