# Changing behaviour Roomba 880

Tags: roomba

I've seen that it is possible to use some micro controller to send commands to the Roomba through the SCI but I was more interested in changing the behavior of the roomba operation (e.g: change the priority of the behaviours)

Is there some IDE for roomba?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to alter behavior priorities or an IDE to alter the software on Roombas. You can use the OI to control and interact with it though using a computer, Arduino, Raspberry Pi, or other serial communication capable device.

See [this answer](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/a/7424/9743) for resources on using OI.

Comment: Why are you interested in modifying behavior priorities? Maybe there is an alternative (I can't comment on the actual question yet...)

Answer (score 0):

To expand on Jonathan's answer:  While you cannot change code or low-level behavior priorities on the Roomba, the [OI Spec](http://www.irobot.com/~/media/MainSite/PDFs/About/STEM/Create/iRobot_Roomba_600_Open_Interface_Spec.pdf) does give you access to some high-level behaviors such as: "Clean", "Max Clean", "Spot Clean", "Dock", etc.  And it gives you full control of the motors and access to all the sensor data including button presses, schedule, and IR commands received.  So you could write your own *new-and-improved* Roomba behaviors if you'd like.

Comment: Thanks for the link, this is very interesting and useful information. And with newer roomba is it possible? (for example with [Roomba 890](https://smartercomputingblog.com/roomba-690-vs-890/#iRobot_Roomba_890_8211_Smart_Choice_for_home))

Comment: I believe it is supported by all Roombas except the 900 series.